# Rust code panic using threads and channels

Tags: rust

I am writing my first Rust program but run into a panic. The code works up until the panic comment, is there something obvious I have missed here?

```
fn print_num(n:i32)
{
    println!("Hi! {}", n);
}

fn main() 
{
    let (s, r) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();
    let (s1, r1) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        let i  = r.recv().unwrap();
        print_num(i);
        s1.send(i+1).unwrap();
    });
    s.send(0).unwrap();
    println!("Got back {}", r1.recv().unwrap());
    // Panic code below
    s.send(1).unwrap();
    println!("Got back {}", r1.recv().unwrap());

    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second call to `s.send()` returns a [`SendError`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.SendError.html). The docs read:

> A send operation can only fail if the receiving end of a channel is disconnected, implying that the data could never be received.

Your receiver `r` is moved into the thread, reads one message, and then is destroyed. The next call has no one to receive the message<sup>1</sup>. Perhaps you wanted your thread to process messages repeatedly in some sort of loop?

Related: [Receiver closing and returning a SendError on attempt to send over channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46995458/receiver-closing-and-returning-a-senderror-on-attempt-to-send-over-channel)

<sup>1. This may not *always* panic since its dependent on thread execution order.</sup>